# Lag when recording with xvidcap?

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics, desktop-recording

I used Xvidcap to record my desktop, but the quality of video was too bad (it lagged so much). I also tried with all output formats that xvidcap support, increase the frame-per-second as much as possible and the quality always at 100% but nothing changed.

[Click to see my video on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbSa6T3Bx-Q)

[image]

I'm using 11.04 (unity) with compiz enabled.

My card is ATI/AMD Mobility 5450 and all drivers were installed and activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to gtkRecordMyDesktop solves the problem. Just select one workspace (instead of the "whole" desktop by default) and the video looks nice.

[Click to see video on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=31B2Y9WboOU)

PS: sorry for the terrible sound. ^_^